# How to skip prompts in Azure Cli?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, azure-cli

I have created a cluster using Terraform in Azure. To access it in Azure CLI, I need to run

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <rg name>  --name <cluster name>
```

When we run the command, it sets a kubeconfig file in our local directory. As I create and destroy terraform files multiples times, cluster will be created and destroyed and everytime you need to run above aks command to use kubectl.

So, I used local-exec for it but when you run the az aks command second time, it prompts for overwrite permission.

A different object named flixtube-aks already exists in your kubeconfig file.
Overwrite? (y/n):

How to skip this. **-y** option didnt work

-y option didnt work. What is the option that selects yes or every prompt in Azure CLI?

Comment: have you checked the docs? I am not a user of azure but the docs have an option `--overwrite-existing` which is defined as `Overwrite any existing cluster entry with the same name.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-get-credentials

Comment: Read the doc + learn to use the help flag: az aks get-credentials --help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @*Chris Doyle*, `--overwrite-existing` is the parameter that overwrites the clusters with same name without prompting us. It worked for me as well.

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group HariTestRG  --name nov9pipeline973b --overwrite-existing
```

[image]

Refer to the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-get-credentials-optional-parameters) given by @*Chris Doyle* for related information, or we use the --help parameter to get related parameters along with their definitions and usage in Command Line tool itself suggested by @*CSharpRocks*.

[image]